# Add Watermark image to PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm trying to add watermark to pdf aready exist in a folder inside my project, I'm using iTextSharp.
Everything is going well and debugging the code is going well, but when finished and I try to open the PDF with watermark just worked on, the file is damage.

Here is my piece of code

```cs
string sourceFilePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/uploadfiles/PDFFileName.pdf");
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(sourceFilePath);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(200, 30, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.Clear(Color.White);
graphics.DrawString(text, new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new PointF(0.4F, 2.4F));
bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploadfiles/Image.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
bitmap.Dispose();
var img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("~/uploadfiles/Image.jpg"));
img.SetAbsolutePosition(200, 400);
PdfContentByte waterMark;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);
    int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
    {
        waterMark = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);
        waterMark.AddImage(img);
    }
    bytes = stream.ToArray();
}
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/uploadfiles/Image.jpg"));
File.WriteAllBytes(sourceFilePath, bytes);
```

[image: the pdf file after open]

Comment: Both PdfReader and PdfStamper implement IDisposable, so you should apply the using pattern, so they get closed and disposed appropriately.

Comment: Indeed, **you have to close the `stamper` before retrieving the bytes**, either explicitly (`stamper.Close()`) or implicitly (`using PdfStamper stamper = ...`).

Comment: @mkl I closed the stamper, The PDF file not damaged, Opening without error, but the watermark not show up !

Comment: You put the image on the `UnderContent`. If the existing content is drawing on the whole page opaquely, you won't see anything put under it, i.e. on the `UnderContent`.

Comment: @mkl How can I make it show?

Comment: You could add the image to the `OverContent` with transparency, either using simple alpha value transparency or using a blend mode like **Darken** or **Multiply**.